# Altering open source code

Tags: java, jar

Assume that I am using an open source jar file in my project which is of size 11mb. But I am not utilizing this jar fully (I'll never utilize in the future too). I know that I just need couple of classes from this jar which does my job. In such case, can I just delete the other classes in the jar file and use it?

I'll make sure that whatever the classes remain in the jar is complete by itself. Meaning, these classes do not depend on any other classes in the jar. So Can I just remove the unwanted classes in the jar so that the jar file gets reduced? If I do this job, it it legal? Am I allowed to do such stuff and use in my project?

Comment: What is the licence of the project ?

Comment: That depends on the license.

Comment: What open license is the source distributed under?

Comment: To be specific, I am trying to alter smartGWT jars.
smartgwt.jar and smartgwt-skins.jar

Comment: is there any specific reason why do you want to strip the JAR file?

Comment: @PeterMmm Out of curiosity: which open source license would prevent you from doing this? (assuming it's an internal project, not a distributed one)

Comment: @nablex I'm not an expert for licensing but I think OSS can use some standard (GPL,LGPL,ASF) and probably some of them do not allow repacking binaries (but I don't know) and, of course, any self-edited license by the author that can contain any clauses as well.

Comment: Because our project runs on a machine which doesn't have enough storage capacity. This jar file is of 11mb which is of no use to us. So we are interested in only one (of 100) feature this jar offers. approximately 10 classes in this jar do this job and other classes we want to remove. So that the jar file size can be reduced from 11mb to approximately 1mb.

Comment: @PeterMmm I can't (off the top of my head) think of any open source license that precludes this (if it's used for an internal project). Probably partly because it would be entirely unenforceable.

Answer (score 1):

SmartGWT appears to use the [LGPL licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License).  This means you can link to it even in a proprietary closed-source application without the need to release your source code if you distribute it.

However, this freedom *may not* apply if you modify the library.

> A program that contains no derivative of any portion of the Library, but is designed to work with the Library by being compiled or linked with it, is called a "work that uses the Library". Such a work, in isolation, is not a derivative work of the Library, and therefore falls outside the scope of this License.

It could be argued that chopping out bits of the library creates a derivative work even though you've not altered the source code itself, but IANAL.

Of course, if you are not distributing your project (for example, it's an internal business application for your company) then I don't believe the requirement to release your source code applies even with a derivative work.